# Creating a property class

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Below is my url parameter:

```
private final static String REST_HOST = "localhost address";
private final static String REST_CONTEXT = "/newwebservices/rest/";
```

If I give local host address it will work only in my system. but I need to run in different system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`

See documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html